# Issues with Margin/ Padding - Intermediate CSS Student

Tags: css, tumblr

I'm trying to figure out if the padding is adjustable in this

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="branding">
     <h1>
    {block:IfHeaderImage}<a href="/"><img src="{image:Header}" alt="{Title}" /></a>    {/block:IfHeaderImage}

     {block:IfNotHeaderImage}<a href="/">{Title}</a>{/block:IfNotHeaderImage}
     </h1>
</div><!-- #branding -->
```

And the associated CSS:

```
#header #branding {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto 3px;
    {block:IfNotHeaderImage}padding: 40px 0;{/block:IfNotHeaderImage}
    width: 900px;
}
```

I tried: adding a height property and changing the padding, but nothing worked. This is being done in Tumblr ([this site](http://thelunaticexpress.tumblr.com/)), and it has been a bit finicky.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the padding has been applied (40px top and bottom, the space above and below the title text).

Answer (score 0):

It's fine in Chrome. See screenshot: http://cl.ly/3z2c3D18291K260s2D1K